# Eloquent get all columns but check distinct on one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've seen none eloquent ways of doing this task but I'm trying to figure if it can be done easier in laravel eloquent.

I have a table and want to retrieve all columns but have them distinct by one column only.

so for example; from this information below i would want to just retrieve all the data related to alex and steve.

```
id  name    active  site_id
1   alex    1       1
2   steve   1       1
3   alex    1       1
```

Comment: you can use groupBy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
     ->where('active', '=', 1)
     ->groupBy('name')
     ->get();
```

Here you can get all the results group by the name for only the active users. Also you have to have in mind that when you use either distinct or group by you are getting an aggregate and if the site_id or active have different values you are going be unable to identify them that why I added the where to get only active users as an example.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you should use groubBy ... but first you must disable strict mode for your mysql in config\database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT',
```

---

```
        'strict' => true,   *// **make if false***
```

then:

```
$values=MyModel::select('*')->groubBy('name')->get();
```